# group by + counting different column values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I have a simple table with `id, gender, age and favoriteMovie`.

Gender column has values male and female only.

I want to display all movie titles from movies column (group by movies) and in two separated columns number of males and number of females voting on selected movie.

Something like `count(gender = 'male') as male, count(gender = 'female') as female`

Database is ms-sql 2008

Any sugestion greatly appreciated

Comment: Which sql? Microsoft? Oracle? Which version of RDBMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *case* syntax (while change `count` into `sum`):

```
   select favoriteMovie as movie, 
          sum(case 
                when gender = 'male' then
                  1
                else
                  0 
              end) as male,
          sum(case 
                when gender = 'female' then
                  1
                else
                  0 
              end) as female
    from MyTable
group by favoriteMovie
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very good with pivots, but this worked for me.

```
declare @t table (id varchar(55),gender varchar(55),age varchar(55),favoriteMovie varchar(55))

insert into @t values(1,'m',16,'star wars')
insert into @t values(2,'f',16,'star trek')
insert into @t values(3,'m',16,'star trek')
insert into @t values(4,'f',16,'star wars')
insert into @t values(5,'m',16,'star wars')
```

And then query.

```
select favoriteMovie, sum([m]) as "m",sum([f]) as "f"
from @t
    pivot 
    (
    count(gender)
    for gender in ([m],[f])
    ) as pt
group by favoriteMovie
```